# How to disable the ad while use YoutubePlayerView?

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

When I use YouTubePlayerView in Android, it's showing the ad before the video starts.

[image]

But I make sure the video source doesn't have ad. And how can I disable the ad? Below is my code:

```
@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
    if (!b) {
        youTubePlayer.cueVideo(mYoutubeId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `youTubePlayer.loadVideo(mYoutubeId);` instead.